# How to parse a single word from a line of text with sscanf

Tags: c, scanf

For example, given this line of text from a file

```
Today: Wed @2p,@3p,5
```

How would I just get "@2p" using sscanf? Right now I am using this code:

```
char 1st[3];
char 2nd[3];
int num;

sscanf(str,"%*[^:]%*[^\t]%s,%s,%d", 1st, 2nd, &num);
printf("1st = %s\n", 1st);
printf("2nd = %s\n", 2nd);
printf("num = %s\n", &num);
```

and the output is

```
1st = Wed
2nd = 'empty characters'
num = 'empty characters'Wed
```

What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: How does this compile?  An identifier shouldn't start with a digit.

Answer (score 1):

The below fails as `"%*[^:]"` scans `"Today"`, then `"%*[^\t]"` scans in `":"`, `"%s"` scans in and does not save `"\t"`, continues scanning and saves `"Wed"` into an array that is too small leading to undefined behavior.

```
sscanf("Today:\tWed @2p,@3p,5", "%*[^:]%*[^\t]%s,%s,%d", 1st, 2nd, &num);
```

The below fails as `"%*[^:]"` scans `"Today"`, then `"%*[^\t]"` scans in `": Wed @2p,@3p,5"`, leaving nothing for `"%s"`.  It also does not check the results of `sscanf()`.  Always check the result to insure valid results.

```
sscanf("Today: Wed @2p,@3p,5", "%*[^:]%*[^\t]%s,%s,%d", 1st, 2nd, &num);
```

Further `"@2p"` cannot fit in a `char [3]` array.  Need room for the null character.

---

Decide what constitutes acceptable characters: the *scanset* and the maximum number of characters.  Check results

```
#define Word_Max 3
#define Prefix "%*[^@]"
#define ScanSet "%3[A-Za-z0-9@]"

char *str = "Today: Wed @2p,@3p,5";
char word[2][Word_Max + 1];
int num;

if (3 == sscanf(str, Prefix ScanSet "," ScanSet ",%d", word[0], word[1], &num)) {
  printf("'%s' '%s' %d\n", word[0], word[1], num);
} else {
  puts("Fail");
}
```

Output

```
'@2p' '@3p' 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your `%*[^\t]` "eats up" just the semicolon left by the `%*[^:]`. So:
`%*[^:]%` gets `Today`
`*[^\t]%` gets `:`
`%s` gets `Wed`
and since after `Wed` there is no comma, following `%s` get nothing

Following code will get you `@2p` in the char array:

```
sscanf(str, "%*[^@]%[^,]", 1st);
```